# Get variable and htaccess not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, pagination

I am using htaccess to generate the following url

```
http:/localhost/classifieds/9/my-classified-title-goes-here
```

using

```
RewriteRule ^aggelies/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ aggelies.php?id=$1&category=$2 [NC]
```

But in the specific page i also need to have pagination in the form of

```
http:/localhost/9/classifieds/my-classified-title-goes-here/?page=2
```

but when i cannot pass the page number in the code.

```
$page_number = (isset($_GET['page']))? $_GET['page'] : '1';
echo $page_number;
```

seems to not work

Comment: i corrected it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the QSA (QueryStringAppend) flag

```
RewriteRule ^aggelies/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ aggelies.php?id=$1&category=$2 [NC,QSA]
```